# как сделать строчки в таблице

Tags: строки, текст

сейчас текст пишется в одну строчку. мне надо чтобы я мог использовать br
в каком файле менять?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день! Для переноса строк с помощью br нужно вставлять его в файле .html в конце строки. После него будет перенос.